# Linkbutton opens a modalpopup but the popup its immediately closed

Tags: c#, javascript, web-parts

I am creating a webpart with an asp linkbutton which needs to open a configurable page in the modal popup.

The modal popup is opened, but its closed immediately.
I put href # but its not working.

If I check the html generated is:

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl38_g_69332c4e_2a87_4bb4_ad70_f7debbd14e91_LnkButton" onclick="OpenModalPopup('www.google.com', '800', '300' );" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl38$g_69332c4e_2a87_4bb4_ad70_f7debbd14e91$LnkButton','')">
```

ascx or webpart file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenModalPopup(pageUrl, widthParameter, heightParameter) {
        var options = { url: pageUrl, width: widthParameter, height: heightParameter, showClose: true };
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
    }
</script>
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="pwcLinkButton" ID="LnkButton" runat="server" href="#"></asp:LinkButton>
```

.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;

namespace xx.SP.xx.WebParts.VisualWebParts.LinkButton
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public partial class LinkButton : WebPart
    {
        private string _LinkText;
        private Uri _Link;
        private Boolean _OpenModal;
        private int _Width;
        private int _Height;

        [WebBrowsable(true), WebDisplayName("LinkText"), WebDescription("Text for the link"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), Category("xx- xx"),
        System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
        public string LinkText
        {
            get { return _LinkText; }
            set { _LinkText = value; }
        }

        [WebBrowsable(true), WebDisplayName("Link"), WebDescription("Link"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), Category("xx- xx"),
        System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
        public Uri Link
        {
            get { return _Link; }
            set { _Link = value; }
        }

        [WebBrowsable(true), WebDisplayName("OpenModal"), WebDescription("OpenModal"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), Category("xx - xx"),
        System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
        public Boolean OpenModal
        {
            get { return _OpenModal; }
            set { _OpenModal = value; }
        }

        [WebBrowsable(true), WebDisplayName("Width"), WebDescription("Width"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), Category("xx- xx"),
        System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
        public int WidthPopup
        {
            get { return _Width; }
            set { _Width = value; }
        }

        [WebBrowsable(true), WebDisplayName("Height"), WebDescription("Height"),
       Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), Category("xx- xx"),
       System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
        public int HeightPopup
        {
            get { return _Height; }
            set { _Height = value; }
        }

        // Uncomment the following SecurityPermission attribute only when doing Performance Profiling on a farm solution
        // using the Instrumentation method, and then remove the SecurityPermission attribute when the code is ready
        // for production. Because the SecurityPermission attribute bypasses the security check for callers of
        // your constructor, it's not recommended for production purposes.
        // [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
        public LinkButton()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (LnkButton != null && Link !=null && LinkText != null)
            {
                LnkButton.Text = LinkText;
                if (OpenModal)
                {
                    LnkButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OpenModalPopup('" + Link.ToString() + "', '" + WidthPopup.ToString() + "', '" + HeightPopup.ToString() + "' );");
                }
                else
                {
                    LnkButton.Attributes.Remove("onclick");
                    LnkButton.PostBackUrl = Link.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this and see if it helped:

```
LnkButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OpenModalPopup('" + Link.ToString() + "', '" + WidthPopup.ToString() + "', '" + HeightPopup.ToString() + "' ); return false;");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's not your popup that's getting closed, but your link causes postback so the page is refreshed. If your link onclick handling function returns false it will be interpreted by browser to cancel link clic, hence not causing postback. So changing this single line to:

```
LnkButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OpenModalPopup('" + Link.ToString() + "', '" + WidthPopup.ToString() + "', '" + HeightPopup.ToString() + "' ); return false;");
```

should do the trick.